# Streaming audio from the browser to a node.js server with a specific MIME type

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

**What I need:**
Streaming live audio from the browser to a node.js server in WAV format.

**Sounds fairly simple - The Problem:**
Using [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) you get the audio-stream BUT in `audio/webm` format. The node.js server is connected to a speech-to-text engine(deepspeech) which CAN ONLY process the stream in WAV format.

**What already works:**
I can already record a fixed length WAV audio blob (via [RecorderJs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)) and send that finished recording to the node.js server and get its stream from `readFileSync` server side. Repository [here](https://gitlab.com/johannes819/deepspeech_node_angular) (master working only). But I don't have a fixed recording anymore and want to live-stream that audio continuously.

As of now I am unsure if that is within the possibilities of node.js or any existing library. I've looked into [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), but didn't find a way to change the encoding of a stream with that. I was only able to change the encoding of a fixed file/blob with ffmpeg.

I'd appreciate it if someone could lead me into the right direction so I know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg is the way to go.

> I've looked into ffmpeg, but didn't find a way to change the encoding of a stream with that.

Use `-` for the input file, and `-` for the output file.  Then use STDIN/STDOUT streams on your Node.js child process.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this correctly...which input/output files do you mean? I just receive a stream, thats all

Comment: Right, so when you execute FFmpeg as a child process, instead of specifying an input file name, just use a single hyphen `-` as a filename.  This tells FFmpeg to expect a stream of input on STDIN.  For the output, also use `-` as the filename, which tells FFmpeg to output to STDOUT.

Comment: That works like a charm if I create the stream by reading in a example file. However if I stream from the browsers Microphone I get the error: `stdout pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
`. How would you continuously stream audio from the browser to the server? Currently Im doing it with Websockets and send a chunk whenever one is available, but that doesn't seem to be working as expected

Comment: @JohannesBeiser Generally speaking, that method works.  For testing purposes, set an output file instead, but leave `-` for STDIN.  There's probably an issue with the specifics of what container formats you're using.  (By the way, I built a nearly identical project awhile back for Facebook.  You can see the code here:  https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example  The only difference is that in your case, you're using the stream from MediaRecorder, rather than CanvasCaptureMediaStream.)